# iOS7 programming -- how to make view controller wait for data to load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am running on Xcode 5.1. I am working on a school project where we need to load tweets in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and after that we need to display the fetched data on a view controller.

I am using interface builder because I think it is simpler, so to answer my question please keep in mind that I am looking for solution with interface builder.

My problem is:
The tweets loading function in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in `AppDelegate` runs in a separate thread. I know if you are programmatically pushing the view controller in `AppDelegate` then you can wait for the tweets to be loaded before you initialize the view controller. But since I am using the interface builder the view controller is always initialized at start, even before the tweets loading function is finished. Therefore I am looking for a way for function in `AppDelegate` to notify the instance of the view controller that story board created, to reload its data once all the required tweets are downloaded.

Simply put:
How do I access the instance of any view controller that's created by the interface builder from `AppDelegate`? Is this a right practice?

I've googled a lot of solutions but all of them involved creating a new instance, which is different than the one that is already created at run time.

Comment: you don't want you view controller to wait. you want it to be informed. the key is "asynchronous loading" or fetching or what ever. search for that. I vote for closure, as this question is too broad.

Comment: I agree with you, I am looking for way to inform the view controller instance inside AppDelegate.

Comment: Why don't you just load the tweets from the view controller that needs them?

Comment: I did and it did not work. Inside viewDidLoad I have [appDelegate fetchData];, followed by [self updateTable];. But the problem is that updateTable executed before fetchData finished loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something along the lines of the following:

- You want asynchronous data loading when your application begins
- You don't want the user to be able to interact with the app until there is data to display.

What I would do for this is:

Dont fetch the data in did-finish-launching
Get the instance of your viewcontroller by using the 'rootViewController` property :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    MYVIEWCONTROLLER *controller = (MY_ROOT_VIEW_CONTROLLER *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [controller triggerFetch];
    ...
    return YES;
}
```

in `triggerFetch` you would create add a `UIActivityIndicator` or progress bar to the main view and add a callback for the fetch function. After the fetch is complete you would remove the loading view and display the fetched content.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is very helpful. This is what I did in did finish launching: PersonListViewController *controller = (PersonListViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [controller updateTable];
But I am getting error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController updateTable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ab2ba50'   I believe I need to set the person list view controller to initial view controller in interface builder?

Comment: Sorry I missed this earlier. The reason it is failing is that, as the exception indicates, `self.window.rootViewController` is a `UITabBarController` instance, not a `PersonListViewController` instance. You can access the `PersonListViewController` by doing `UITabBarController *tab = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;` and then `PersonListViewController *controller = [tab.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: Then you would call `[controller updateTable];`

Answer (score 0):

If your UI elements are bound to the model properly, changes to your model should reflect in the view automatically.

I'm not sure exactly what UI interface elements you are using. I'm assuming you have a UITableViewController displaying your tweets, and you are using your appDelegate as the UITVCDelegate as well to give it info on how many cells, dimensions, and the data for each cell inside its UITableView. And in the end you want it to reload data after you are done with fetching the tweets.

The simplest way would be to call `[tableView reloadData]` on the tableView (You can access it from the UITVC). But, that's just based on my assumptions being true about you using a UITableView to display the tweets.

Cheers!